# Java Scanner Input Errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a simple Java game called 21 sticks. In the beginning, I want to ask the user his/her name, so I can refer to them by their name for the rest of the game. However, when I use my code(below), first `input` has the eclipse red squiggly line under it, meaning error. This is not compiling. I have tried to Google the way to fix this, or if there is a better way to do it, but I have fond nothing. I have tried changing `input` to `inputMap`, but then the `nextLine` doesn't work. I would like to know why this is showing up as an error, and if there is a better way to ask for the user's name.

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwentyOneSticks { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is your name?")
    String userName = input.nextLine()
    int numofSticks = 21;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to go first? (Y/N)");
    String goFirst = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Well, considering you're trying to use the `Scanner` before it exists ... that could be a problem.

Comment: @pita everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwentyOneSticks { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
 System.out.println("What is your name?");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   <--- moved it here
 String userName = input.nextLine();
 int numofSticks = 21;

  //Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in);   <-- what is use of this?
  System.out.println("Would you like to go first? (Y/N)");
  String goFirst = input.nextLine();
```

You have to declare (and initialise) a variable before using it.  Also some semicolons were missing.

Comment: There's a few semi-colons missing as well after `println` and `nextLine()`.

Comment: lol - Oh boy, one of those days

Comment: @user2310289 Thank you. The `Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in); ` was for something later in my code, i just forgot to take it out.